# linear mixed model with discrete and continuous covariates

Tags: regression, mixed-model

please help me out with this...

if I want to include both discrete and continuous variables in a linear mixed model, what do I do? I tried including them in the model `lmer (dependent ~ independent + discrete variable + discrete variable + continuous variables +(1|sub), data)`, but the output showed the same as the model with only dependent and independent V `lmer(dep ~ indep +(1|sub), data)`  does anyone has encountered similar issue? could you provide some hint to me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This should not be the case, at least the additional variables should be displayed. What do you mean by "output"? Have you used `summary(model)`? Maybe you can post the output of `summary(model1)` and `summary(model2)` and `str(data)`?

Comment: You really need to tell us more details dor this to be answerable ... please tell us more, but as an edit to the question and not only in comments!